# Coupons and distribution

Tags: probability

A publicity company puts grocery coupons in 10000 mailboxes. Each coupon has a chance 1/15 to be used. Let X be the number of coupons that are used. Calculate E(X) and Var(X) (give an exact answer, not an approximate one).

I am thinking that this is a binomial distribution with $E(X)=10000/15$ and $Var(X)=(2000/3)(14/15)$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: You have the correct answers... so is there anything you are confused about?

Comment: Yes, although it's a bit odd that you chose to reduce $10000/15 = 2000/3$ in the variance but not the mean.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to make sure this was binomial. So the distribution would look like (10000 C x) (1/15)^x (14/15)^10000-x ?

Comment: Sorry my notes are very messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* by "Each coupon has a chance 1/15 to be used" you actually mean, "each mailbox has $1/15$ chance of receiving a coupon", then the count of coupons used in mailboxes does indeed have a binomial distribution, with parameters $n{=}10\,000$ and $p{=}1/15$.

*Is* that what you meant?

And if so, the calculations you have are correct; though they can be simplified some more.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what the problem means. Thank you!

Comment: Usually mailed coupons reach mailboxes with probability very close to 1. The model as stated needs no corrections.